# Why is SIGIO not in the POSIX signal specification?

Tags: posix

In the 2004 version of the [1003.1 POSIX standard by the Open Group](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/basedefs/signal.h.html) there is no mention of SIGIO.

Why is that?

Comment: You could improve this question by explaining why you would expect it to be POSIX. As it stands, I could simply answer with "because SIGIO isn't POSIX".

Comment: A related question is https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/377209/ .