# Does Linux follow System V conventions by default terminating on SIGIO?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, signals

In the book Unix Network Programming there is the following statement:

> We should establish the signal handler before setting the owner of the
>   socket. Under Berkeley-derived implementations, the order of the two
>   function calls does not matter because the default action is to ignore
>   SIGIO. Therefore, if we were to reverse the order of the two function
>   calls, there is a small chance that a signal could be generated after
>   the call to fcntl but before the call to signal; if that happens, the
>   signal is just discarded. Under SVR4, however, SIGIO is defined to be
>   SIGPOLL in the  header and the default action of SIGPOLL
>   is to terminate the process. Therefore, under SVR4, we want to be
>   certain the signal handler is installed before setting the owner of
>   the socket.

In the file `signal.h` in the Linux kernel, the POSIX behavior, which follows System V is quoted *as a comment*:

```
*   +--------------------+------------------+
 *  |  POSIX signal      |  default action  |
 *  +--------------------+------------------+
 *  |  SIGHUP            |  terminate   |
 *  |  SIGINT            |  terminate   |
   ....
 *  |  SIGPROF           |  terminate   |
 *  |  SIGPOLL/SIGIO     |  terminate   |
 *  |  SIGSYS/SIGUNUSED  |  coredump    |
 *  |  SIGSTKFLT         |  terminate   |
   .... etc.
```

However, I could not find any place in the source where this policy was actually implemented. There did not appear to be any equation setting SIGIO equal to SIGPOLL. So, does Linux follow the Berkeley behavior or the System V behavior?

Answer (score 2):

```
#define SIGIO       29
#define SIGPOLL SIGIO
```

https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/v4.12/include/uapi/asm-generic/signal.h#L39